# Custom Query won't pass to view through viewmodel

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, linq, razor

I have a custom query that I want to pass to the view through a viewmodel.  I can pass the query directly to the view and it work but when I try to pass it to the view with a view model I get errors. I know there has to be a simple answer but I'll be hanged if I can figure it out.

The class

```
 namespace TADSVer2_1.Models
{
  public class TailNo
  {
    public string TailNos { get; set; }
    public string Base { get; set; }
    public string ACType { get; set; }
  }
}
```

Query The query works fine I get the data I need.

```
 var test3 = _context.Aircrafts.Where(c => c.BaseId == 4).Include(c => c.ACType).Include(c => c.Base)
            .Select(c => new TailNo {
              TailNos = c.TailNumber,
              ACType = c.ACType.Type,
              Base = c.Base.Name }).ToList();
```

The view

```
@model IEnumerable<TADSVer2_1.ViewModels.AircraftViewModel>
@{
  ViewBag.Title = "Index";
  Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
}
<ul>
   @foreach (var i in Model)
  {
    <li>
       @i.TailNos " " @i.Base " " @i.ACType
    </li>
  }
</ul>
```

The above code works fine but when I use the view model I get errors as listed below.

ViewModel

```
namespace TADSVer2_1.ViewModels
{
  public class AircraftViewModel
  {
    public IEnumerable<TailNo> TailNo { get; set; }
  }

}
```

The first error message I receive is:

```
 'AircraftViewModel' does not contain a definition for 'TailNos' and no extension method     'TailNos' accepting a first argument of type 'AircraftViewModel' could be found (are you missing a      using directive or an assembly reference?)
```

So I remove the IEnumerable from the View and I get this Error:

```
  foreach statement cannot operate on variables of type 'AircraftViewModel' because 'AircraftViewModel' does not contain a public instance definition for 'GetEnumerator'
```

So I replaced the IEnumerable in the view and tried this in the viewmodel and got this compile error

```
 public TailNo TailNo { get; set; }

     Error  CS1061  'AircraftViewModel' does not contain a definition for 'TailNos' and no   accessible extension method 'TailNos' accepting a first argument of type 'AircraftViewModel' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)  TADSVer2_1  D:\Programing_ Examples\MVC_Examples\MVC Exercises\TADSVer2_1\TADSVer2_1\Views\Aircraft\Index.cshtml    12  Active
```

So I am stuck on how to get the custom query to use the viewmodel.  Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
@model TADSVer2_1.ViewModels.AircraftViewModel
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Index";
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
}
<ul>
    @foreach (var i in Model.TailNo)
    {
            <li>
                @i.TailNos " " @i.Base " " @i.ACType
            </li>
    }
</ul>
```

Comment: Thank you very much, that worked. I am now sure what kind of brain freeze I had.  Think the problem I had were to many Enumerables  in the path and to answer your last question, checking test3 it showed:  (new System.Collections.Generic.Mscorlib_CollectionDebugView<TADSVer2_1.Models.TailNo>(test3).Items[0]).ACType.  Thanks Again!!!!!

Answer (score 0):

You are going through a IEnumerable of AircraftViewModel data which then has an IEnumerable of TailNo. You have to do a nested foreach (example below):

```
@model IEnumerable<TADSVer2_1.ViewModels.AircraftViewModel>
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Index";
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
}
<ul>
    @foreach (var i in Model)
    {
        @foreach (var tail in i.TailNo)
        {
            <li>
                @tail.TailNos " " @tail.Base " " @tail.ACType
            </li>
        }
    }
</ul>
```

Comment: Still not working. I am now getting the error message:  '   The model item passed into the dictionary is of type 'TADSVer2_1.ViewModels.AircraftViewModel', but this dictionary requires a model item of type System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1[TADSVer2_1.ViewModels.AircraftViewModel]''.

Comment: Make sure that the model is defined as: model IEnumerable<TADSVer2_1.ViewModels.AircraftViewModel> - sounds like the IEnumerable has been removed and single item is being passed

Comment: In the view on the top line is:    @model IEnumerable<TADSVer2_1.ViewModels.AircraftViewModel>  and in the ViewModel the query results are assigned to:    public IEnumerable<TailNo> AircraftId { get; set; }  When I compile I get no errors until the page tries to open.  So I am stumped.

Comment: Is it because var test3 is an List of TailNo as you are doing the select after the query? So on top of your view it should be IEnumerable<TailNo>? If that is the case, changing that in the view is the only thing as your foreach should then work

Comment: I check and it is a List of TailNo because I can use a foreach on it before it is set to the view model. I change the view and it did not work. I still get the error message:  The model item passed into the dictionary is of type 'TADSVer2_1.ViewModels.AircraftViewModel', but this dictionary requires a model item of type 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1[TADSVer2_1.Models.TailNo]'.  Thanks for all the help I hope we can figure this out because I need to use a ViewModel to send the list to the View.

Comment: I have added another answer. It seems like the view is being passed a single AircraftViewModel object and thats why I have changed to model to take a single object and go through the TailNo IEnumerable.

Comment: If you hover over var test3, can you tell me what it is? What is its type?